# pass variable into url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem when passing two variables into URL. it works fine in localhost, but not in hosting (linux hosting)..

i use form_open(); in view

and the controller (pickup.php) :

```
<?php

function verifikasi($request_id, $unik) {
    $pickup = $this->input->post('pickup');

    $this->load->model('excel');
    $this->load->model('request');
    $data['results'] = $this->request->pickup($request_id, $unik);
    foreach ($data['results'] as $key) {
        $req_id = $key['req'];
        $data['undg'][$req_id] = $this->excel->info($req_id);
        foreach ($data['undg'] as $value) {
            if (isset($_POST["pickup"])) {
                $date = array(
                    'status' => '2',
                    'address' => $this->input->post('from_address'),
                    'lat' => $this->input->post('lat'),
                    'lon' => $this->input->post('lon'),
                    'pickup_time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($pickup))
                );
                $this->db->where('request_Id', $request_id);
                $this->db->update('request', $date);
                $date = array(
                    'from_address' => $this->input->post('from_address'),
                );
                $this->db->where('request_Id', $request_id);
                $this->db->update('excel', $date);
                $data['msg'] = "SUKSES !!! Kami akan Menghubungi anda.";
            }
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('info', $data);
}
```

is there any additional value that I should put in the form_open() ?

Comment: which one do you trying to post, can you post your controller and view complete so people know what your problem now ?

please try echo your varibale inside function

Comment: thank you, it solved now.. but i have a new problem here..

Comment: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/a5027/public_html/application/controllers/Pickup.php:2)

Comment: what session do you mean ? your controller doesn't tell session

Comment: check your controller for empty spaces before <?php  or ?> after closing tag

Comment: exactly.. i didnt find any 'session_start()' there but the page keeps telling me that..

Comment: thank Poria, works fine now..

Comment: Make sure the class and file names have the first letter only upper case on CI3 versions of CodeIgniter `Pickup.php` and `<?php class Pickup extends CI_Controller{}`